# Filter an Array containing several arrays with objects inside

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to filter a multidimensional array with the inner array containing an object. Every post I have found on here looks like the example below, and all the solutions were pretty much the same and were not successful for me.

`let arr = [ { name: 'brent', age: 123 } ];`

This is closest I can get, I can console log the filter and see it filtering, but I cannot find out why my array is returning undefined.

```js
let filteredData = [];
let responseData.results = [...]; //The contents of this array are below in the next block

filteredData = responseData.results.forEach((group) =>
{
    group.filter(({ customerName }) => customerName.includes(searchTerm));
});

console.log(filteredData); //returns as undefined?
```

```js
let responseData.results = [
  [
    {
      "id": "e62d6610-04aa-4e92-806f-0449ab3becad",
      "customerName": "Immunics",
      "enduserName": "Everest",
      "productId": 4,
      "productName": "fugiat",
      "createdBy": "Keith",
      "created": "2013-10-31",
      "expires": "2011-03-03"
    },
    {
      "id": "3be2967d-cd92-488b-97e3-a8001da6d1c5",
      "customerName": "Techtrix",
      "enduserName": "Lunchpad",
      "productId": 2,
      "productName": "sit",
      "createdBy": "Odessa",
      "created": "2010-02-25",
      "expires": "2011-05-22"
    },
    {
      "id": "a67861ae-4e1b-4637-af45-096d6ed7a50f",
      "customerName": "Kaggle",
      "enduserName": "Strezzo",
      "productId": 4,
      "productName": "consequat",
      "createdBy": "Matilda",
      "created": "2010-09-05",
      "expires": "2011-08-01"
    },
    {
      "id": "182f84d5-fc27-414c-b011-0e26a9b8e688",
      "customerName": "Idealis",
      "enduserName": "Blurrybus",
      "productId": 0,
      "productName": "veniam",
      "createdBy": "Merle",
      "created": "2012-02-02",
      "expires": "2014-05-22"
    },
    {
      "id": "cc05e705-3b5f-4fe6-8c6e-1873fd3834ac",
      "customerName": "Furnigeer",
      "enduserName": "Harmoney",
      "productId": 5,
      "productName": "anim",
      "createdBy": "Humphrey",
      "created": "2010-08-15",
      "expires": "2012-06-06"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "f2d0ff8e-31ad-4415-8089-cce9df68d119",
      "customerName": "Neocent",
      "enduserName": "Inear",
      "productId": 3,
      "productName": "duis",
      "createdBy": "Christian",
      "created": "2010-01-23",
      "expires": "2013-05-18"
    },
    {
      "id": "485095fa-ac86-475c-9a7c-ad449334060d",
      "customerName": "Digiprint",
      "enduserName": "Bristo",
      "productId": 0,
      "productName": "occaecat",
      "createdBy": "Moran",
      "created": "2010-09-30",
      "expires": "2014-06-14"
    },
    {
      "id": "d3cacece-1f96-4055-8672-4e506b73e437",
      "customerName": "Nexgene",
      "enduserName": "Viasia",
      "productId": 7,
      "productName": "exercitation",
      "createdBy": "John",
      "created": "2012-07-23",
      "expires": "2014-03-31"
    },
    {
      "id": "7fe019e3-7175-48a0-9e2d-1681ce1bfb64",
      "customerName": "Quilm",
      "enduserName": "Hawkster",
      "productId": 3,
      "productName": "do",
      "createdBy": "Stevens",
      "created": "2014-04-28",
      "expires": "2013-07-27"
    },
    {
      "id": "7c83a2ea-aa43-4413-af86-02fcd20740e3",
      "customerName": "Zillacon",
      "enduserName": "Zanity",
      "productId": 5,
      "productName": "dolor",
      "createdBy": "Cathryn",
      "created": "2010-07-05",
      "expires": "2011-11-26"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "2fc29e02-ae0c-413f-ba5a-270a8ba73e5a",
      "customerName": "Zepitope",
      "enduserName": "Cujo",
      "productId": 4,
      "productName": "quis",
      "createdBy": "Aurora",
      "created": "2013-03-22",
      "expires": "2014-09-27"
    },
    {
      "id": "07020c5e-7512-456b-af77-3f95d3b8724b",
      "customerName": "Melbacor",
      "enduserName": "Elemantra",
      "productId": 0,
      "productName": "amet",
      "createdBy": "Pitts",
      "created": "2010-09-06",
      "expires": "2014-08-14"
    },
    {
      "id": "be9ecd9d-7060-43a2-83b8-b05c52954b9c",
      "customerName": "Combot",
      "enduserName": "Circum",
      "productId": 7,
      "productName": "ex",
      "createdBy": "Mindy",
      "created": "2013-07-05",
      "expires": "2014-07-26"
    },
    {
      "id": "991a986b-bd3b-426a-9fc8-113a312c4a19",
      "customerName": "Canopoly",
      "enduserName": "Accusage",
      "productId": 3,
      "productName": "proident",
      "createdBy": "Cohen",
      "created": "2014-02-09",
      "expires": "2011-03-17"
    },
    {
      "id": "d843e391-c56d-4dc4-a1d1-dc1b936bc9bd",
      "customerName": "Mobildata",
      "enduserName": "Eargo",
      "productId": 4,
      "productName": "culpa",
      "createdBy": "Kathie",
      "created": "2013-04-03",
      "expires": "2012-07-03"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "940c6df9-0bbb-43d0-a463-23ba6754a0bb",
      "customerName": "Signity",
      "enduserName": "Bovis",
      "productId": 8,
      "productName": "occaecat",
      "createdBy": "Monroe",
      "created": "2013-09-03",
      "expires": "2014-03-23"
    },
    {
      "id": "7479851f-8bba-448b-9af4-75076d81c61f",
      "customerName": "Zilladyne",
      "enduserName": "Mazuda",
      "productId": 8,
      "productName": "voluptate",
      "createdBy": "Bertie",
      "created": "2012-05-03",
      "expires": "2010-09-11"
    },
    {
      "id": "dda601dc-6671-43ca-847f-53a90e61f123",
      "customerName": "Farmex",
      "enduserName": "Greeker",
      "productId": 7,
      "productName": "eiusmod",
      "createdBy": "Jody",
      "created": "2010-06-17",
      "expires": "2010-09-19"
    },
    {
      "id": "dee1e763-bc49-4b14-87c9-41c7dee01763",
      "customerName": "Fibrodyne",
      "enduserName": "Besto",
      "productId": 7,
      "productName": "ex",
      "createdBy": "Arlene",
      "created": "2012-01-29",
      "expires": "2013-10-14"
    },
    {
      "id": "89d69c32-c801-469f-b40f-3d8c85184b08",
      "customerName": "Sustenza",
      "enduserName": "Omatom",
      "productId": 9,
      "productName": "consectetur",
      "createdBy": "Pruitt",
      "created": "2011-03-24",
      "expires": "2014-09-13"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "2a1d82fc-d7df-4fde-bd4c-97fabccf217e",
      "customerName": "Essensia",
      "enduserName": "Comverges",
      "productId": 8,
      "productName": "aliquip",
      "createdBy": "White",
      "created": "2010-06-23",
      "expires": "2014-04-02"
    },
    {
      "id": "f16e04f8-8431-43ac-8315-9822435fe9b0",
      "customerName": "Accruex",
      "enduserName": "Gluid",
      "productId": 6,
      "productName": "veniam",
      "createdBy": "Kim",
      "created": "2010-07-14",
      "expires": "2010-04-09"
    },
    {
      "id": "47728404-a86a-4f91-a4fb-d54c6da88a74",
      "customerName": "Miracula",
      "enduserName": "Gonkle",
      "productId": 2,
      "productName": "proident",
      "createdBy": "Moon",
      "created": "2013-07-08",
      "expires": "2010-09-10"
    },
    {
      "id": "96810031-64e0-4565-ae0f-308db3fbf7eb",
      "customerName": "Viocular",
      "enduserName": "Toyletry",
      "productId": 3,
      "productName": "sit",
      "createdBy": "Callahan",
      "created": "2014-10-28",
      "expires": "2011-01-11"
    },
    {
      "id": "fd223cf3-7f1b-4afb-bccf-cf1907a33334",
      "customerName": "Genekom",
      "enduserName": "Chorizon",
      "productId": 3,
      "productName": "ipsum",
      "createdBy": "Calhoun",
      "created": "2013-09-12",
      "expires": "2011-02-27"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return a value. Switch `.forEach` to a `.map`

Comment: I tried that as well, I should have added that. Let me try again maybe I missed something the first time I used map

Comment: Yes I forgot to delete the brackets when I updated this. @Joel thank you!

Comment: Working as expected once you untangle your variable naming. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: It should not return undefined. Is this your full code? You call `let filteredData = [];` and never reference `filteredData` again until `console.log(filteredData);`. So `filteredData` should be `[]`. You are missing some code here. As one of the answers states - you have a naming issue and Typescript would catch these issues immediately. Edit: @JustBarnt you replied to me after an edit to your post. The original post should not have returned undefined. You changed variable names then commented it works as you stated it should.

Comment: @Diesel It would return undefined and it did, because I didn't switch my map to an implicit inline return at first, and before that I was using a forEach loop which I found out doens't return data.

Comment: Please stop updating your original question as this changes the question entirely and the effort people put down in trying to solve your question.

Comment: Understood, I reset it to the original state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two common ways of going about this.

Either you can do a `map`:

```
const filteredData = responseData.results.map((group) => {
  return group.filter(({ customerName }) => customerName.includes(searchTerm));
});
```

Or even shorter with the implicit inline return:

```
const filteredData = responseData.results.map((group) =>
  group.filter(({ customerName }) => customerName.includes(searchTerm))
);
```

---

Or a `reduce` to get rid of the non-filtered objects that provide a hit from `responseData`.

```
const filteredData = responseData.results.reduce((result, group) => {
  const match = group.filter(({ customerName }) =>
    customerName.includes(searchTerm)
  );
  if (match) result.push(match);
  return result;
}, []);
```

More information:

[MDN - reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

[MDN - map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

It's a variable naming mistake. You haven't changed `filteredData`. Rename `filteredLicenses` to `filteredData` and it should work.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer (and a reason to flag as typo)

Comment: I just forgot to rename my variable when I copied it from my code.

Comment: You mean that's why your code doesn't work? Or can you edit your question to not have the mistake so it's a better example?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to filter each group (sub array) and push those filtered groups to the resulting array if the filtered group has at least one item. Using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method will push empty groups to the resulting array and that's why `reduce` should be used to prevent that.

Here's a live demo:

```js
const results = [
    [{
        "id": "e62d6610-04aa-4e92-806f-0449ab3becad",
        "customerName": "Immunics",
        "enduserName": "Everest",
        "productId": 4,
        "productName": "fugiat",
        "createdBy": "Keith",
        "created": "2013-10-31",
        "expires": "2011-03-03"
      },
      {
        "id": "3be2967d-cd92-488b-97e3-a8001da6d1c5",
        "customerName": "Techtrix",
        "enduserName": "Lunchpad",
        "productId": 2,
        "productName": "sit",
        "createdBy": "Odessa",
        "created": "2010-02-25",
        "expires": "2011-05-22"
      },
      {
        "id": "a67861ae-4e1b-4637-af45-096d6ed7a50f",
        "customerName": "Kaggle",
        "enduserName": "Strezzo",
        "productId": 4,
        "productName": "consequat",
        "createdBy": "Matilda",
        "created": "2010-09-05",
        "expires": "2011-08-01"
      },
      {
        "id": "182f84d5-fc27-414c-b011-0e26a9b8e688",
        "customerName": "Idealis",
        "enduserName": "Blurrybus",
        "productId": 0,
        "productName": "veniam",
        "createdBy": "Merle",
        "created": "2012-02-02",
        "expires": "2014-05-22"
      },
      {
        "id": "cc05e705-3b5f-4fe6-8c6e-1873fd3834ac",
        "customerName": "Furnigeer",
        "enduserName": "Harmoney",
        "productId": 5,
        "productName": "anim",
        "createdBy": "Humphrey",
        "created": "2010-08-15",
        "expires": "2012-06-06"
      }
    ],
    [{
        "id": "f2d0ff8e-31ad-4415-8089-cce9df68d119",
        "customerName": "Neocent",
        "enduserName": "Inear",
        "productId": 3,
        "productName": "duis",
        "createdBy": "Christian",
        "created": "2010-01-23",
        "expires": "2013-05-18"
      },
      {
        "id": "485095fa-ac86-475c-9a7c-ad449334060d",
        "customerName": "Digiprint",
        "enduserName": "Bristo",
        "productId": 0,
        "productName": "occaecat",
        "createdBy": "Moran",
        "created": "2010-09-30",
        "expires": "2014-06-14"
      },
      {
        "id": "d3cacece-1f96-4055-8672-4e506b73e437",
        "customerName": "Nexgene",
        "enduserName": "Viasia",
        "productId": 7,
        "productName": "exercitation",
        "createdBy": "John",
        "created": "2012-07-23",
        "expires": "2014-03-31"
      },
      {
        "id": "7fe019e3-7175-48a0-9e2d-1681ce1bfb64",
        "customerName": "Quilm",
        "enduserName": "Hawkster",
        "productId": 3,
        "productName": "do",
        "createdBy": "Stevens",
        "created": "2014-04-28",
        "expires": "2013-07-27"
      },
      {
        "id": "7c83a2ea-aa43-4413-af86-02fcd20740e3",
        "customerName": "Zillacon",
        "enduserName": "Zanity",
        "productId": 5,
        "productName": "dolor",
        "createdBy": "Cathryn",
        "created": "2010-07-05",
        "expires": "2011-11-26"
      }
    ],
    [{
        "id": "2fc29e02-ae0c-413f-ba5a-270a8ba73e5a",
        "customerName": "Zepitope",
        "enduserName": "Cujo",
        "productId": 4,
        "productName": "quis",
        "createdBy": "Aurora",
        "created": "2013-03-22",
        "expires": "2014-09-27"
      },
      {
        "id": "07020c5e-7512-456b-af77-3f95d3b8724b",
        "customerName": "Melbacor",
        "enduserName": "Elemantra",
        "productId": 0,
        "productName": "amet",
        "createdBy": "Pitts",
        "created": "2010-09-06",
        "expires": "2014-08-14"
      },
      {
        "id": "be9ecd9d-7060-43a2-83b8-b05c52954b9c",
        "customerName": "Combot",
        "enduserName": "Circum",
        "productId": 7,
        "productName": "ex",
        "createdBy": "Mindy",
        "created": "2013-07-05",
        "expires": "2014-07-26"
      },
      {
        "id": "991a986b-bd3b-426a-9fc8-113a312c4a19",
        "customerName": "Canopoly",
        "enduserName": "Accusage",
        "productId": 3,
        "productName": "proident",
        "createdBy": "Cohen",
        "created": "2014-02-09",
        "expires": "2011-03-17"
      },
      {
        "id": "d843e391-c56d-4dc4-a1d1-dc1b936bc9bd",
        "customerName": "Mobildata",
        "enduserName": "Eargo",
        "productId": 4,
        "productName": "culpa",
        "createdBy": "Kathie",
        "created": "2013-04-03",
        "expires": "2012-07-03"
      }
    ],
    [{
        "id": "940c6df9-0bbb-43d0-a463-23ba6754a0bb",
        "customerName": "Signity",
        "enduserName": "Bovis",
        "productId": 8,
        "productName": "occaecat",
        "createdBy": "Monroe",
        "created": "2013-09-03",
        "expires": "2014-03-23"
      },
      {
        "id": "7479851f-8bba-448b-9af4-75076d81c61f",
        "customerName": "Zilladyne",
        "enduserName": "Mazuda",
        "productId": 8,
        "productName": "voluptate",
        "createdBy": "Bertie",
        "created": "2012-05-03",
        "expires": "2010-09-11"
      },
      {
        "id": "dda601dc-6671-43ca-847f-53a90e61f123",
        "customerName": "Farmex",
        "enduserName": "Greeker",
        "productId": 7,
        "productName": "eiusmod",
        "createdBy": "Jody",
        "created": "2010-06-17",
        "expires": "2010-09-19"
      },
      {
        "id": "dee1e763-bc49-4b14-87c9-41c7dee01763",
        "customerName": "Fibrodyne",
        "enduserName": "Besto",
        "productId": 7,
        "productName": "ex",
        "createdBy": "Arlene",
        "created": "2012-01-29",
        "expires": "2013-10-14"
      },
      {
        "id": "89d69c32-c801-469f-b40f-3d8c85184b08",
        "customerName": "Sustenza",
        "enduserName": "Omatom",
        "productId": 9,
        "productName": "consectetur",
        "createdBy": "Pruitt",
        "created": "2011-03-24",
        "expires": "2014-09-13"
      }
    ],
    [{
        "id": "2a1d82fc-d7df-4fde-bd4c-97fabccf217e",
        "customerName": "Essensia",
        "enduserName": "Comverges",
        "productId": 8,
        "productName": "aliquip",
        "createdBy": "White",
        "created": "2010-06-23",
        "expires": "2014-04-02"
      },
      {
        "id": "f16e04f8-8431-43ac-8315-9822435fe9b0",
        "customerName": "Accruex",
        "enduserName": "Gluid",
        "productId": 6,
        "productName": "veniam",
        "createdBy": "Kim",
        "created": "2010-07-14",
        "expires": "2010-04-09"
      },
      {
        "id": "47728404-a86a-4f91-a4fb-d54c6da88a74",
        "customerName": "Miracula",
        "enduserName": "Gonkle",
        "productId": 2,
        "productName": "proident",
        "createdBy": "Moon",
        "created": "2013-07-08",
        "expires": "2010-09-10"
      },
      {
        "id": "96810031-64e0-4565-ae0f-308db3fbf7eb",
        "customerName": "Viocular",
        "enduserName": "Toyletry",
        "productId": 3,
        "productName": "sit",
        "createdBy": "Callahan",
        "created": "2014-10-28",
        "expires": "2011-01-11"
      },
      {
        "id": "fd223cf3-7f1b-4afb-bccf-cf1907a33334",
        "customerName": "Genekom",
        "enduserName": "Chorizon",
        "productId": 3,
        "productName": "ipsum",
        "createdBy": "Calhoun",
        "created": "2013-09-12",
        "expires": "2011-02-27"
      }
    ]
  ],
  /** 
  * a function that filters the "results" array based on a "searchTerm"
  */
  filterResults = searchTerm => results.reduce((r, group) => {
    const f = group.filter(({customerName}) => customerName.includes(searchTerm));
    /** only push NON empty groups (sub arrays) to the final array */
    f.length && r.push(f);
    return r;
  }, []);

/** test "fileterResults" function */
console.log(filterResults("Farmex"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%!important;
}
```

Comment: what does `f.length && r.push(f);` do compared to Joels answer with `if(match) results.push(match)`

Comment: The same, but `f.length && r.push(f)` is a bit shorter and relies on the `&&` (AND) operator that invokes `r.push(f)` when `f.length` is *truthy*. If `f.length` is *falsy*, and thanks to the `&&` operator, the `r.push(f)` won't be executed.